# How to ignore the null values in the first date?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I have this table:

```
dates   var1    var2
2004    null    null
2005    null    null
2006    null    null
2007    null    null
2008    25      null
2009    30      null
2010    50       30
2011    60       50
2012    null     70
2013    null     80
2014    null     90
```

I need a query with below results:

```
dates   var1    var2
2008    25      null
2009    30      null
2010    50       30
2011    60       50
2012    null     70
2013    null     80
2014    null     90
```

I tried with:

```
select * from table where var1 is not null
```

but it is necessary to leave the subsequent nulls.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been clearer if you had stated that you want to select all rows where not both `var1` and `var2` are `null`, or in other words where either of the two is not `null`. Then it's as easy as

```sql
select * from table where var1 is not null or var2 is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
select * from table where nvl(var1,var2) is not null
```

Comment: your option is elegant([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ceae5adda30bf6544fe0982c093c9489))

Answer (score 0):

The logic seems to be that both of the columns shouldn't be null at the same time for the returning set. This means consider the cases that both columns are `null` at the same time 
(`var1 is null and var2 is null`) and take Complement set (`not`) set of it. So, you need :

```
select *
  from tab
 where not (var1 is null and var2 is null)
```

or an arithmetical option would be finer by considering `nvl2()` function of Oracle through `addition` :

```
select *
  from tab
 where nvl2(var1,1,0) + nvl2(var2,1,0) > 0
```

where `0` is returned for `null` values, `1` is returned for `non-null` values from each column values stated within `nvl2()` function as the components of the addition.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e2b5f61582af0c3d96749325264d99ce)</kbd>